# Unable to eliminate last talbeviewcell (when search is empty)

Tags: ios, google-cloud-firestore

I use this code to search for all files that are off in "review",
And there is a button to change "review" to "on". When "review" is changed to "on"(because the code only searches for "off"), the tableviewcell will disappear normally.

But every time the last stroke will not disappear(tableview can't find the file), you need to restart the app to clear the tableviewcell,

Why is this?

```
let db = Firestore.firestore()
        db.collectionGroup("TWDBuy").whereField("review", isEqualTo: "off")
            .order(by: "date", descending: true)
        
            .addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error) in
```

This is tableview

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return postArray.count
    }
    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TWDBuyPGTableViewCell") as! TWDBuyPGTableViewCell
        
        let post = self.postArray[indexPath.row]
        let date = post.date
        
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier:"Asia/Taipei")
        dateFormatter.locale = Locale.init(identifier: "zh_Hant_TW")
        
        dateFormatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")
        let dateStr = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
        
        if postArray[indexPath.row].review2 == "未確認"{
            cell.review2.textColor = UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 192.0/255.0, blue: 0.0/255.0, alpha: 1)
        }else{
         
            cell.review2.textColor = UIColor(red: 55.0/255.0, green: 163.0/255.0, blue: 152.0/255.0, alpha: 1)
        }
        
       
        cell.quantity.text = "數量："+postArray[indexPath.row].quantity+" USDT"

        cell.coin.text = "匯入： TWD "+postArray[indexPath.row].coin
        cell.address.text = postArray[indexPath.row].address
        cell.network.text = postArray[indexPath.row].network
        cell.email.text = postArray[indexPath.row].email
        cell.review2.text = postArray[indexPath.row].review2
        cell.uid.text =  postArray[indexPath.row].uid
        cell.useruid = post.uid
        cell.useremail = post.email
        cell.commentDelegate2 = self
        cell.time.text = dateStr
        cell.idimage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: postArray[indexPath.row].ID5))
       
        cell.deleteThisCell2 = { [weak self] in
            self!.delete2(didSelectRowAt: indexPath, cell: cell)
        }
        cell.deleteThisCell3 = { [weak self] in
            self!.delete3(didSelectRowAt: indexPath, cell: cell)
        }
        let settings = Settings.defaultSettings
            .with(actionOnTapOverlay: Action.dismissOverlay)
            .with(actionOnDoubleTapImageView: Action.zoomIn)
        addZoombehavior(for: cell.idimage, settings: settings)
        
        getUserPortfolio(didSelectRowAt: indexPath)
        //刷新
        self.usertableview.es.addPullToRefresh {
            [unowned self] in
            /// Do anything you want...
            /// ...
            /// Stop refresh when your job finished, it will reset refresh footer if completion is true
            self.usertableview.es.stopPullToRefresh()
            /// Set ignore footer or not
            self.usertableview.es.stopPullToRefresh()
        }
        return cell
    }
```

I have updated the tableview, and there is nothing in the snapshot. If the tableviewcell has a "review" off, modifying each "review" to on will reduce it normally, but the last one will not disappear (firebase "review" is all on)

Comment: You'll need to post the table-view code as well as what's going on in the snapshot listener. Btw, I'd probably have made `review` a `Bool` instead of a `String` for the sake of efficiency.

Comment: I have updated the tableview, and there is nothing in the snapshot. If the tableviewcell has a "review" off, modifying each "review" to on will reduce it normally, but the last one will not disappear (firebase "review" is all on)

Comment: You said to review Bool instead of String, can you give me some code to learn? Thank you very much

Comment: You have much too much going on in `cellForRowAt`. All you should be doing in `cellForRowAt` is injecting the cell with values. If there are computations that need to be done, do them beforehand in a separate place and then reload the table-view. You certainly should not be doing any pull-to-refresh or cell deletion logic in `cellForRowAt`. Create a function or an object that grabs the data, one that parses the data, one that handles pull-to-refresh, one that deletes cells, etc. This is the foundation of object-oriented-programming--independent objects doing their own specific tasks.

Comment: May I ask where should I write the pull-down refresh? Is it tableviewcell?
May I ask what kind of way do you mean separate processing? func?

Comment: You can create objects or just put them in different functions in the same object. Pull-to-refresh would first require determining when the user is pulling to refresh which would be done in the table-view/scroll-view delegate `scrollViewDidScroll` method. From within that method, you'd ideally call a function that would then grab the data and parse it into more table-view cells. The cells themselves only deal with styling. OOP is all about a separation of powers. This is largely because when you encounter a bug or want to expand functionality, there is no guesswork because of the organization.

Comment: To be a really good programmer, before you write any code, think it out in the simplest terms possible. Sketch it on paper with boxes (that represent objects). The simpler you keep your code, always the better, every time, without exception. Often times code inherently becomes complex by its sheer size which is why a separation of responsibility is even more important, if not critical. Think like a caveman. Keep it simple.